# select given column in delimited text file using regex

Tags: regex, text-parsing

I have a text file like below

```
Name     Phone
ABCDE    12345
FGHIJ    67890
KLMNO    23876
```

I want to select only values under Name ( or values under Phone) using RegEx
How should I approach this?

Thanks

Comment: You can replace `([A-Z]{5}) +(\d{5})` by `\1` or `\2`.

Answer (score 1):

Do values under name only have uppercase letters? If this is the case, then:

`[A-Z]+` - will only give you names.

`[0-9]+` - will only give you phone numbers.

Square brackets are called character classes, basically when you say [abc] this means "Find me text which has a or b or c", notation with - in it, [A-Z] takes ASCII code of A, and ASCII code of Z, and basically puts every ASCII character between these two values into brackets, so you would have every uppercase alphabet letter in brackets.

Plus sign (+) after square brackets means: "Find occurrences of square brackets one or more time".

**Note:**

Plus sign doesn't only work for square brackets. For example if you say `a+` this would find you text where letter `a` appears one or more time.